# Accessing Sharepoint lists from a Standalone Application

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, wsdl, knime

I have a Standalone application, which needs to access a Sharepoint list. I bumped into a few articles, mentioning Web Service is the way to go about it.

But I am unable to find a step by step path to write a web service to fetch list from sharepoint. In addition to this, the application can take a WSDL file as an input.

Please let me know how to proceed about this scenario.

Comment: what version of SharePoint are you working with?

Comment: The answer to this question will depend on what version of SharePoint you are using.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SharePoint 2007, then web services is the only way to do this.  [Here is a list of the different web services available.](http://tonytestasworld.com/post/2008/02/24/SharePoint-2007-Web-Services.aspx)

If you are using SharePoint 2010 you can use the [client object model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee857094%28office.14%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the SharePoint webservice Lists.asmx (both in SharePoint 2007 and 2010)

1. In your application, add a web reference 'http://(sharepoint-url)/_vti_bin/lists.asmx'
2. Once done, you can use the method **GetList**.

For more information, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlist(v=office.12).aspx#Y82